# Which way for converting an int to double in Java is preferred?

Tags: java

Almost complete beginner here, I'm working on an exercise for mooc.fi and for part of the exercise, I have to find the average of a set of numbers.

Here is my fist option that seems to work:

```
    int sum = 0;
    int numOfNum = 0;
    double average = 0;

    System.out.println("Give numbers:");

    while(true) {

        int input = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());

        if(input == -1) {
            System.out.println("Thx! Bye!");
            break;
        }

        sum += input;
        numOfNum ++;
        average = sum / (double) numOfNum;
```

The second option is :

```
    int sum = 0;
    double numOfNum = 0;
    double average = 0;

    System.out.println("Give numbers:");

    while(true) {

        int input = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());

        if(input == -1) {
            System.out.println("Thx! Bye!");
            break;
        }

        sum += input;
        numOfNum ++;
        average = sum / numOfNum;
```

Both give me a "correct" answer but I'm not sure which one (or if there's a better way I didn't write) is better to use. Explain like I'm 5 if possible, old dog learning new trick on this one. Appreciate any responses and apologies if I'm not putting this in the right place, this is all new to me.

Comment: You're asking for an opinion, so you'll probably get both answers. In my opinion, because  `numOfNum` is a counter, it should not ordinarily be a double. It should be some form of integer or specialized Counter object (e.g. for very large values). That aside, there's really no difference between your two code examples other than, perhaps, that incrementing integers is more efficient than incrementing doubles, in some situations.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no difference in both of yours. Why don't you declare your variables are double so you don't need to cast the result?